# Так что как-то так

Tags: пунктуация

Не могу объяснить правило, но мягкий знак пишется, так что() как-то так...

Какой знак ставится перед "как-то"? Мне кажется, в таких случаях, тут есть интонационная пауза. Или мне только кажется?:)

Comment: Здравствуйте verzatrana.

Если кто-то кое-где у нас порой ..., тогда так что как-то так.

Comment: Здравствуйте,@Галактион. Позвольте подредактировать: "Если кто-то кое-где у нас порой...,тогда так что ? как-то так: стоим горой!" (на месте знака вопроса - вообще никаких знаков!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы прочитала без паузы. Если пауза и есть,то она чисто авторская, интонационная, показывающая прерывание речи, а это значит, что лучше поставить многоточие. Запятая точно неуместна, ведь так что - союз со значением следствия, а оборота после него нет, нет причин обособления. Тире возможно, но многоточие задержку передаёт лучше.

Comment: Вообще фраза разговорная, устная, не могу предположить, зачем ее писать? Если предположить, что здесь, на форуме, то лучше обойтись без этого "так что как-то так". В устной речи за счет интонации ещё звучит, а на письме ... Скопление "так" и "как" заставляет вчитываться, а смысла-то особого выражение не несет.

Comment: Никакого знака не нужно. КАК-ТО - обстоятельство при сказуемом ТАК в безличном предложении. Союз "так что" присоединяет придаточное. Всё просто. Согласна с Ларой, фраза разговорная.

Comment: А почему это предложение безличное?

Comment: Потому что подлежащего нет и не может быть.

Comment: Почему ж не может?  Это неполное предложение, смотря что вставишь:так что всё происходит как-то так-подлежащее всё ;так что пишется (или надо писать)как-то так-безличное.Наличие обстоятельства говорит только о наличии сказуемого, наличие подлежащего не опровергает.

Answer (score 0):

"Как-то" - это не обстоятельство при сказуемом - это просто часть фразеологизма. Вообще "так что как-то так" - это устоявшееся выражение, фразеологизм, а фразеологизмы запятых не требуют.

Comment: Фразеологизм тоже имеет определенное строение,и его нужно обозначить. Думаю, что здесь можно использовать термин "предложение фразеологизированной структуры", но эти предложения не бывают однокомпонентными. Можно предположить, что подлежащее пропущено: так что (всё) как-то так.

Comment: Вполне возможно. Мне нравится Ваша дотошность. В мире безумия и показухи это одна из самых приятных вещей. Я лишь хочу обратить Ваше внимание, что выражение "как-то так" является паразитическим. Есть же слова-паразиты и есть фразеологизмы-паразиты. Это, на мой взгляд, тот самый случай. В 70-е - 80-е годы бытовало другое - "это самое"; в 90-е оно уступило место слову с частицей "как бы", которое плавно перетекло в современно "как-то так" (так как-то). Обратите внимание, все примеры содержат неопределённость, а это значит, что их распространённость заключает серьёзный социальный смысл.